# How to Organize a Database on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to organize data from one sheet into several different sheets for example if on my raw data sheet I had four people with their favorite food:

```
1 | Rice
2 | Pasta
3 | Rice
4 | Cheese
```

Is there any way to sort through this sheet and have all of the people who say like rice show up on a second sheet. Something like sheet "Rice" would look like:

```
1 | Rice
3 | Rice
```

Essentially trying to do a lookup or index match that can skip "Pasta" or "Cheese" people without leaving an empty row in the "Rice" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you something to start with:

I have here `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. Sheet1 contains the raw list and Sheet2 will be populated with the filtered values.

Here's my code:

```
function main(){

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
      var ctr = 1;
      var sheetRange ="" ;
      var myActiveSheet = "";  

      var my2DArray =  getValue("rawSheet!A1:B9");

      if(my2DArray){
          for( var i =0; i<my2DArray.length; i++){
               if(my2DArray[i][1] == "Rice"){
                   Logger.log((my2DArray[i][0]));
                   //ctr will ensure the new values don't overwrite the previous values
                   sheetRange = 'A'+ctr;
                   //activate the sheet which will contain the 'filtered list'
                   sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[2]).getRange(sheetRange).setValue(my2DArray[i][0]);
                   //make sure the new values don't overwrite the previous values so increment it (row1, row2, row3, etc)
                   ctr++;
                } 
          }
      }
}

//this function will fetch the values from the raw list
function getValue(a1notationString) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
  var data = sheet.getRange(a1notationString).getValues();

  return data;
}
```

Here's the **rawSheet** (sheet 1/sheet.getSheets()[ 1 ]):

[image]

Here's the **filteredSheet** (sheet 2/sheet.getSheets()[ 2 ]):

[image]

You'll notice that all Names who eat Rice are moved to the **filteredSheet**

For more info, get familiar with [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of VLOOKUP()? This allows you to search through a range and extract a value from a column based on matching a column.

from one of the first google results for Google Sheets vlookup (https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/):

The syntax for the Google Sheets VLOOKUP function is as follows:

VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
The first 3 arguments are required, the last one is optional:

Search_key - is the value to search for (lookup value or unique identifier). For example, you can search for the word "apple", number 10, or the value in cell A2.

Range - two or more columns of data for the search. The Google Sheets VLOOKUP function always searches in the first column of range.

Index - the column number in range from which a matching value (value in the same row as search_key) should be returned.

The first column in range has index 1. If index is less than 1, a Vlookup formula returns the #VALUE! error. If it's greater than the number of columns in range, VLOOKUP returns the #REF! error.

Is_sorted - indicates whether your Vlookup formula should return the nearest match (TRUE) or exact match (FALSE).

If is_sorted is set to FALSE, the Vlookup formula searches with exact match.
If the lookup column (the first column of range) contains 2 or more values exactly equal to search_key, the 1st value found is returned. If an exact match is not found, the #N/A error is returned. In most cases, it's recommended to Vlookup with exact match.

If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted (default), a Vlookup formula returns an approximate match. The lookup column must be sorted in ascending order, i.e. from A to Z or from smallest to largest.
Vlookup with approximate match works this way: the formula searches for the exact match first. If the exact match is not found, it searches for the closest match that is less than or equal to search_key. If all values in the lookup column are greater than the search key, the #N/A error is returned.